# How to store in a list a generic class without specifying the type?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I have the following class:

```
class Parameter<T>
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to have a list like that:

```
class ParameterModel
{
    public List<Parameter<>> Parameters {get;}
}
```

Then I will have code like:

```
...
Parameter<> parameter = parameterModel.Parameters.Where(p => p.Index == "AAA");
if (parameter is Parameter<bool>)
{
    ...
}
else if (parameter is Parameter<int>)
{
    ...
}
...
```

Is this something doable or should I use Inheritance instead of generics?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a case where you want to use inheritance and do dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Why not use `ParameterModel<T>` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Check the Jodrell response please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wouldn't

```
class ParameterModel<T>
{
    public List<Parameter<T>> Parameters { get; }
}
```

do the job?

---

or perhaps you wan't paramters of different types? Then you could do

```
public interface IParameter
{
    string Index { get; set; }
    Type ParameterType { get; }
}

public class Parameter<T> : IParameter
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Type ParameterType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }
}

class ParameterModel
{
    public List<IParameter> Parameters { get; }
}
```

so you could do,

```
var aaaParameter = parameterModel.Parameters.Single(p => p.Index == "AAA");
if (aaaParameter.ParameterType == typeof(bool))
{
    ...
}
else if (aaaParameter.ParameterType == typeof(string))
{
    ...
}
```

---

but, given the bounds of the problem you describe, a simple dictionary might be best.

```
var parameterModel = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

allowing

```
var aaaParameter = parameterModel["AAA"];
if (aaaParameter is bool)
{
    ...
}
else if (aaaParameter is string)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just want one Parameter model as I need to model a list of parameters whatever the backing value type it is. I'll check the type latter when I work with them.

Comment: The second solution looks better, I'll give it a chance.

Comment: You can't switch over a type. Need to use if else chain or switch over `TypeCode`

Comment: @SoMoS, the last option looks straight forward to me.

Comment: @Jodrell This is even worse `is` keyword can't be used with type. It needs a static `Type(class name)`. ex: `obj is String`

Comment: Ah, now this looks good. I should give +1 for you for number of workarounds given

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way - short and sweet:

```
 public class Parameter
 {
     public string Index { get; set; }
     public dynamic Value { get; set; }
 }

 var param1 = new Parameter() { Index = "qw", Value = 34 };
 var param2 = new Parameter() { Index = "qr", Value = "rere" };

 int val1 = (int)param1.Value;
 string val2 = (string)param2.Value;
```

And to get the type:

```
  var t1 = param1.Value.GetType();
  var t2 = param2.Value.GetType();
```

Or something like this in your case:

```
 if (param1.Value.GetType() == typeof(int))
 {...}
 else if (param1.Value.GetType() == typeof(string))
 {...}
```

with a

```
 List<Parameter> myParams=new List<Parameter>();
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use inheritance.**

Here's an example from some recent work:

```
abstract public class AttributeVariant
{
    string key;
    string name;

    public AttributeVariant(string key, string name)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string GetKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public class AttributeVariant<T> : AttributeVariant
{
    T value;

    public AttributeVariant(string key, string name, T value = default) : base(key, name)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public object GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void SetValue(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class AttributeVariant<T, T2> : AttributeVariant<T>
{
    T2 data;

    public AttributeVariant(string key, string name, T value = default, T2 data = default) : base(key, name, value)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public object GetData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void SetData(T2 data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This way I can store the generic class types into a simple variable without any issue. Here's how I used these:

```
static Dictionary<string, AttributeVariant> AttributesList = new Dictionary<string, AttributeVariant>()
{
    { "age", new AttributeVariant<string>("age", "Age") },
    { "arms", new AttributeVariant<string>("arms", "Arms") },
    { "bridge", new AttributeVariant<string>("bridge", "Bridge") },
    { "color", new AttributeVariant<string>("color", "Model") },
    { "condition", new AttributeVariant<string, double>("condition", "Condition") },
    { "full_color", new AttributeVariant<string>("full_color", "Full Color") },
    { "gender", new AttributeVariant<string>("gender", "Gender") },
    { "height", new AttributeVariant<string>("height", "Height") },
    { "lenses", new AttributeVariant<string>("lenses", "Lenses") },
    { "material", new AttributeVariant<string>("material", "Material") },
    { "rim_type", new AttributeVariant<string>("rim_type", "Rim Type") },
    { "shape", new AttributeVariant<string>("shape", "Shape") },
};
```

Comment: And how would you iterate that AttributesList Dictionary and print the "value" field (and it's type) for each entry? Even if you use reflection, you don't know the type before hand. To be more specific how would cast that "value" field to a variable inside the iteration.

Comment: You can retrieve the types of the generic parameters by using .GetType().GetGenericArguments() and adjust the behaviour of your code accordingly. Of course you have to know how to deal with the types beforehand.

If I want to know whether I have a dual or single generic parameter I can either count the length of the array returned by GetGenericArguments() or I can be more specific and do something like

.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AttributeVariant<,>)
.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AttributeVariant<>)